# Возможна ли сноска перед восклицательным знаком?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, сноски

В публиц. тексте есть цитата из Евангелия:

> *Ищите прежде Царствия Божия и сия вся приложатся вам*!

Редактор хочет сделать сноску со ссылкой на Евангелие: Мф 6: 33. Но дело в том, что восклицательного знака в оригинале нет, он поставлен автором, передаёт авторскую эмоцию. Цитата (именно чтобы показать, что это цитата) выделена курсивом, а сам знак нет. Можно ли поставить сноску перед восклицательным знаком, принимая во внимание все сказанное?

> *Ищите прежде Царствия Божия и сия вся приложатся вам*<sup>1</sup>!

Answer (score 1):

Если цитату давать отдельной строкой, то невербальную «авторскую эмоцию» можно отнести лишь к отдельной части фразы, и в скобках. Но знак без определённой атрибутики существовать не может:

Ищите прежде Царствия Божия (! — *ред.*) и сия вся приложатся вам.*

Answer (score 0):

Выскажу частное мнение. Знак сноски ставится перед знаком препинания (так было во всех примерах, которые я обнаружил в справочнике Мильчина, хотя я не встретил восклицательного знака в этих примерах). Но не это главное.

Желание автора исказить известную цитату (а замена знаков препинания тоже является таким искажением) я не могу одобрить. Не каждый обратит внимание, что восклицательный знак не выделен курсивом. Это может быть воспринято как попытка ввести в заблуждение. Или нужно передать эмоции каким-то другим способом — это не должно быть сложно, или указать в примечании, что данное предложение является парафразом известной цитаты.